# Как преобразовать 2 строки в словарь?

Tags: python

```
a = "16:00"
b = "go"
```

Есть 2 такие строки, как добавить их в словарь, так чтобы 16:00 было ключом, а "go" было значением?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict[a] = b
```

4 символа

Answer (score 5):

Можно сделать этот словарь так:

```
d = {a: b}
```